# Get text from doc/docx file in pages using Apache tika

Tags: apache-tika

I am using apache tika command line tool to extract text from the doc and docx file. I can get the whole text but i am unable to get them in form of pages so that i can store each page separately. Is there any way to achieve that ?

Comment: Are you aware that the Microsoft Word file format is run-based and not page-based?

Answer (score 1):

Tika uses [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to process Word files (both the old binary- and the newer XML-based flavors).

Since POI (fundamentally) cannot read out those page numbers and Tika is not meant to be a document renderer either, the answer is very simply: **No, this is not possible**.

For a little more insight on why your requirement (from a technical standpoint) does not make much sense, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34812776/5717099).